# Асинхронная анимация jQuery

Tags: jquery, animate

Как мне сделать `animate` и `show` асинхронными (Чтобы выполнялись одновременно) ? Пробовал делать так, но не работает

```
$.when(
    $(".obj1").show(200).promise(), 
    $(".obj2").animate(200).promise())
 .done(function() { //stuff });
```

Код выше естественно сокращенный, но суть я передал

Comment: Так вам нужно синхронно (одновременно) или асинхронно (не одновременно)??

Comment: @yuri в данном случае не знаю как правильно сказать :). Мне нужно одновременно. Есть же синхронный [tag:ajax], который выполняется во время выполнения основного кода, то есть строчка по строчке. Вот я тут и путаюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код, впринципе, рабочий:

```js
$.when(
  $(".obj1").hide(700).promise(),
  $(".obj2").fadeOut(800).promise()
).done(function() {
  console.log('fin')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obj1">1</div>
<div class="obj2">2</div>
```

Анимация выполняется одновременно, по завершении обеих анимаций выполняется код.

Опишите подробнее, что у вас не получилось и что вы хотели сделать.

> Как мне использовать коллбэк только от `hide`

Если вам нужен колбек только от одной анимации, это гораздо проще сделать: Функцию положите 2м аргументом `hide()` (или  `show()`, или  `fadeIn()` и тд)

```js
  
  $(".obj1").hide(700,function() {
      console.log('fin obj1')
  })
  $(".obj2").fadeOut(1000,function() {
      console.log('fin obj2')
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obj1">1</div>
<div class="obj2">2</div>
```

Comment: Как мне использовать коллбэк только от `hide`?

Comment: @Herrgott ответил в тексте ответа

Comment: Что-то я не очень понимаю, я так делал и анимации все равно исполнялись по-очереди

Comment: @Herrgott Такое возможно, если назначать анимацию на один объект

Comment: Да, мне надо на один объект, но вроде это сработало, спасибо

Comment: @Herrgott Так а в вопросе у вас _разные_ объекты. Тогда `animate` вам в помощь - анимируйте несколько свойств в одном `animate`